# Equality of Ranks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A\in \mathbb{F}^{m×n}$. The row rank of $A$ is the dimension of the row space of $A$.

Show that the row rank of $A=$ row rank of its RREF. Show that the row rank of $A$ is equal to rank of $A$.

Hello. Any suggestions, outlines, or hints for this one. I've been really messing it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: the row rank of $A$ is the number of linearly independent rows. When transforming $A$ into its reduced row echelon form, you add multiples of one row to another. Do these row operations affect the independence of the rows involved?

Comment: Nope. But how can I show it?  Is it okay to state it directly?

Comment: @Lostinspace Personally, I would expect that defining row rank and explaining why it is invariant over row operations would be sufficient. However, this depends entirely on the requirements of your instructor.

Comment: Is it suffices to show that elementary row operations preserve the rank of the matrix?

Comment: @Lostinspace Again, this dependents on your instructors requirements. You should consider asking them if such an answer would suffice. You may be expected to demonstrate _why_ row operations perverse the the rank.

Comment: Thanks. I got the first one. How about the second thing that I need to show?

Comment: @Lostinspace How do you define the rank of a matrix?